# Failing to read HTML specified url

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to read a webpage's source but somehow I don't get the right one.

Typing the url in the browser and reading the same url with python returns different results.  I am guessing that's because a script is running in the browser. but I can't seem to understand which script.

My goal is to get the source of the page which I open typing the following url:

> http://www.topshop.com/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/ProductDisplay?beginIndex=1&viewAllFlag=&catalogId=33057&storeId=12556&productId=10366631&langId=-1&sort_field=Relevance&categoryId=208523&parent_categoryId=203984&pageSize=20

The printed HTML source code is not the url I typed but the parent page's source code.

My python script:

```
item_url = 'http://www.topshop.com/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/ProductDisplay?beginIndex=1&viewAllFlag=&catalogId=33057&storeId=12556&productId=10366631&langId=-1&sort_field=Relevance&categoryId=208523&parent_categoryId=203984&pageSize=20'
product_url = urllib.urlopen(item_url)
product_s = product_url.read()
print product_s
```

How do I get the source code (details on the product)?

Comment: Turn off JavaScript in your browser and then load the page. That's what Python is seeing.

Comment: My goal is to get python to see what my browser and not viceversa. is the a way doing that?

Comment: You will need to execute the JavaScript. There's [ghost.py](http://jeanphix.me/Ghost.py/), which is a headless WebKit browser.